# Fetch and Axios not working on React Native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, axios, fetch

I've tried on 3 different projects now to make fetch or axios work and I can't. I have tried changing the android manifest like some people tried in some issues but it doesn't work. Not with await/async, not with promises, not even this super simple example. Not even the finally gets called.

It doesn't return errors, or logs, or anything, nothing happens.

***After further testing, it looks like Mac/IOS works, but Windows/Android doesn't.***

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, Text} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hola');
    fetch('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Hola');
        console.log(response.json());
      })
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch(error => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => console.log('Finally'));
  }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Hola</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "prueba",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling a secure URL, ie `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums`. I have a vague memory that unsecured fetches are not allowed

Comment: @Phil yeah I did, same thing.

Comment: Which `console.log()` calls do you see reported in the console? FYI, your first `.then` callback should `return response.json()` instead of logging it

Comment: @Phil the only console log I see is "hola", nothing after the fetch

Comment: After further testing, it looks like Mac/IOS works, but Windows/Android doesn't

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that you were using `http` instead of `https` and hence it Failed to fetch.

You can write your api call in two ways

**Normal Fetch**

```
const NORMAL_FETCH = () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
    .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((json) => console.log(json))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
    .finally(() => console.log('Finally'));
};
```

**Async/Await** (my preference)

```
const API_CALL_ASYNC_AWAIT = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums');
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();
    console.log(jsonResponse);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/api-call-example)

Change your code to this

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    API_CALL_ASYNC_AWAIT();
    NORMAL_FETCH();
  }, []);

  const API_CALL_ASYNC_AWAIT = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'
      );
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      console.log(jsonResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  const NORMAL_FETCH = () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((json) => console.log(json))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => console.log('Finally'));
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text>Hola</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I actually used HTTPS before and it still didn't work.

Comment: You were not returning the `response.json`. Check my `NORMAL_FETCH` function